# SQL use multiple values from a table to get corresponding values from one field in another table

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have two tables, `attr_tbl` and `freq_tbl`.

**attr_tbl fields:**

```
attr_ky - numeric
attr_name - character
```

Sample attr_tbl:

```
attr_ky | attr_name
   1    |  driver 
   2    |  athlete 
   3    |  parent
```

**freq_tbl fields:**

```
att1 - numeric
att2 - numeric
att3 - numeric
freq - numeric
```

Sample freq_tbl:

```
att1 | att2 | att3 | freq
  1  |   2  |  3   | 1000
```

I would basically like to add three more columns to the **freq_tbl**.
**att1_name**: `attr_name` corresponding to `att1`
**att2_name**: `attr_name` corresponding to `att2`
**att3_name**: `attr_name` corresponding to `att3`

Desired Result:

```
att1 | att2 | att3 | freq | att1_name | att2_name | att3_name
   1 |   2  |   3  | 1000 |  driver   |  athlete  |  parent
```

I know how to do this with multiple sql statements, but I would like to know how to do it with one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample data and desired result added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
select 
    T.att1, 
    T.att2, 
    T.att3, 
    T.freq, 
    A1.attr_name AS att1_name, 
    A2.attr_name AS att2_name, 
    A3.attr_name AS att3_name
from freq_tbl T
    LEFT JOIN attr_tbl A1 ON T.att1 = A1.attr_ky
    LEFT JOIN attr_tbl A2 ON T.att2 = A2.attr_ky
    LEFT JOIN attr_tbl A3 ON T.att3 = A3.attr_ky
```